# How to print \n in a <textarea> using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Ex : `document.write("\n");`

I want to print that `\n` in my `<textarea>`.

Comment: @Dolph: I liked the question much better before you whitewashed it.

Comment: i think we use \n for newline in C compiler too (dont remeber c that much), how to get that \n in C (\\n dosnt work in C)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
document.write("\\n");
```

That will put a "\n" in your text area.

Comment: this answer should be marked wow.......... though i asked the wrong question ...i was suppose to ask this in c language

Answer (score 3):

The `\` starts an escape sequence (for a new line), so you have to escape it to get a literal slash.

```
"\\n"
```

For a textarea, you just write that between `<textarea …>` and `</textarea>` (if you are writing the whole thing with `document.write` or `reference_to_textarea.value = "\\n"` if you are setting it after the element exists in the DOM.